# How is 'Overwatch: Game of the Year Edition' different than 'Overwatch: Origins Edition'

Tags: overwatch, version-differences

On [May 23rd, 2017](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20793056), Blizzard replaced ***Overwatch: Origins Edition*** with the new ***Overwatch: Game of the Year Edition*** in the [Blizzard Store](https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/overwatch).

Looking at the official blog post for [***Overwatch: Game of the Year edition***](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20793056), the GotY edition appears to be identical to the *Origins Edition*, offering the exact same set of rewards.

Even the trailers for the two editions look near identical when compared side by side with the exception that the GotY edition comes with 10 bonus loot boxes. They even reuse the exact same footage for both trailers.

Are there any differences between ***Overwatch: Game of the Year Edition*** when compared to the previous ***Overwatch: Origins Edition***, or are the differences name-only?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Game of the Year Edition has everything from the Origins edition, but also has 10 loot boxes for Overwatch.

Comment: Apparently I'd forgotten that Tracer for HotS was included in the Origins edition.  Whoops.  But yeah, it's pretty much a rename plus tosses in 10 loot boxes.

Comment: What is a loot boxes? Why I'd want one?

Comment: @neves Loot boxes are items that award 4 random cosmetics, guaranteeing that at least one of them is rare or better quality.

Comment: Note that Overwatch: Legendary Edition has replaced the Game of the Year edition and [comes with 10 specific skins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/332801/87105) instead of 10 loot boxes.

Answer (score 6):

**As [Powerlord stated](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/310412/181240), the Game of the Year Edition comes with 10 lootboxes for Overwatch. Aside from that, the two editions are identical.**

#### Both editions include:

- 5 Origin skins for *Overwatch* (Overgrown Bastion, Security Chief Pharah, Strike-Commander Morrison, Blackwatch Reyes, and Slipstream Tracer).
- Tracer Hero for *Heroes of the Storm*
- Baby Winston Pet for *World of Warcraft*
- Overwatch Card Back for *Hearthstone: Heroes of Warcraft*
- Mercy's Wings for *Diablo III*
- Player Portraits for *StarCraft II* (Tracer, Reaper, Pharah, Winston, Bastion, and Soldier: 76)