# What skins are in the Legendary Edition?

Tags: overwatch

Overwatch Legendary Edition replaced the [Game of the Year edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/310395/87105) during the second anniversary.  Instead of coming with 10 loot boxes, it comes with 10 pre-selected skins (5 Epic, 5 Legendary).

Which 10 skins comes with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sony posted a [promotional video](https://youtu.be/CbfbrXTqArU) for the Legendary Edition on the PlayStation Youtube channel; it lists all the skins that come with the Legendary Edition.  They are:

- Epic

  - Carbon Fiber Genji
  - Pale Moira
  - Paragon Reinhardt
  - Winter Widowmaker
  - Shrike Ana
- Origins

  - Security Chief Pharah
  - Strike Commander Morrison Soldier: 76
  - Slipstream Tracer
  - Blackwatch Reyes Reaper
  - Overgrown Bastion
- Legendary

  - Okami Hanzo
  - Valkyrie Mercy
  - Police Officer D.Va
  - Mystery Man McCree
  - Fool Junkrat

Comment: The Origins skins are the same ones that came with the Origins edition and Game of the Year edition that this edition replaces.