# Why haven't I got the Legendary and Epic skins that come with the Overwatch: Legendary Edition?

Tags: overwatch

I recently purchased *Overwatch: Legendary Edition*, because I heard that it comes with some Legendary and Epic skins. This is the only reason I bought the legendary edition.

But I'm disappointed: for some reason I can't see my skins anywhere. How do I activate them? I've tried everything I can and have googled around but with no luck.

Comment: Physical or Digital? What platform?

Comment: It comes with [15 specific skins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/332802/87105) which you should be able to equip in the Hero Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Well. If its a physical disk, it should come with a piece of paper with a code on it that you can use to get your skins. If not, check with each character to see if you got them. There are only about 15 that come with it.